# How to check insertion in another table after insertion

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I have two entities `proposition` and `department`. A proposition has to target at least one department (1-N) and a department can be targeted by 0-N propositions.

So in my database, I have 3 tables : `PROPOSITION`, `TARGET` and `DEPARTEMENT`.

I try to find a way to make sure that after inserting a proposition in `PROPOSITION`, an entry is inserted in `TARGET`. In other word I want to make sure the (1-N) relationship does not become a (0-N) relationship.

Is there a way to do that with a trigger ? Or should I change the structure of my database?

Thanks in advance

[EDIT]
Solution :

A trigger can't do the job as the insertions in `TARGET` depends on a value that is entered asynchronously by the user. For example, if the proposition 1 targets department 2 and 3, in my tables the data are :

```
PROPOSITION
1

TARGET
1 2
1 3

DEPARTMENT 
1  
2 
3
```

Trigger idea : Set a trigger on `PROPOSITION`, after something is inserted .... ?? What do we do ? Wait for an insertion in `TARGET` ? Insert a default value in `TARGET` for the department ? 
So a trigger on `PROPOSITION` is not going to work.

The only solution I found is to restructure my database :

- I added a field `DEPARTMENT_NUMBER` in proposition that can't be NULL.
- I set a trigger on the `TARGET` table to check before insertion that the proposition is not already targeting the department in its attribute.

The method slows the database but it ensures the (1-N) relationship to be respected

Comment: You can do this with a trigger. You don't need to change the db structure.

Comment: I know a trigger can do this insert, where do I get the value I have to insert ? It depends what department the proposition targets ...

Answer (score 0):

The best way of doing this in my opinon would be to create a trigger on Proposition that inserts into Target.

Check this link it should get you started. 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html

Comment: I don't know what to insert, it depends which DEPARTEMENT the PROPOSITION targets !